# Returning documents in Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm absolutely new to Firestore and for some reason I can't get it right.
I'm trying to retrieve documents from it that I've just manually entered. Using node.js I make a call for a database snapshot like in the documentation:

```
db.collection('categories').get()
.then((docs) => {
  res.json(docs)
})
```

But instead of an array of docs or something like this, I get this as a response:

[image: Json result]

`_size` is right, I have two documents in the collection - but I can't find them anywhere. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `docs` variable is of type [QuerySnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.13.x/QueryDocumentSnapshot).  Look at the methods available on that object.  If you just want the raw documents out of it, use the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.13.x/QuerySnapshot#docs) property on it to get an array of [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.13.x/QueryDocumentSnapshot) objects.  Each of those will have a method called [data()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.13.x/QueryDocumentSnapshot#data) on them to get the raw document data.

Comment: It seems it's the right way to do that, thanks, I knew I've missed something obvious! (maybe not so obvious because it's not exactly clearly stated in the documentation)

Comment: Please send feedback about the Firebase documentation!  The team does read it and take it seriously.  The button is in the upper right hand side of every page.